# How to provide unique name for Amazon S3 object?

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon S3 as image hosting and need to upload images keeping their name unique in order to avoid duplications.

I am using the following iOS code:

```
// Following code is iOS but it's really make no difference.  
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:MYKEY inBucket:MYBUCKET] autorelease];
```

What is the best way to ensure that MYKEY is unique?

The key name has really no importance for me and could be pure random string.

Comment: Note, In addition to Alex's answer below, you can also use the `Content-Disposition` header so that your file downloads with the original filename or store it using the custom meta data feature of S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a GUID or UUID in Objective-C](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/09/creating-guid-or-uuid-in-objective-c.html).

Comment: I do exactly this for one of my apps.